# Exercise about map objects $Y^{1}$ ("Conceptual Mathematics Second Edition", p.314, Article V Map objects, Exercise 3)

Tags: logic, category-theory, universal-algebra, enriched-category-theory

Suppose $\mathcal C$ has products and a terminal object $1$. If the map object $Y^{1}$ exists, I'm having trouble proving that $Y^1 \simeq Y$. I thought this would pop-out easily as follows: Let $p: 1 \times Y \rightarrow Y$ denote the right projection. Then the UMP of map objects provides a unique map $\ulcorner p \urcorner : Y \rightarrow Y^{1}$ such that $p = e \circ (1_{1} \times \ulcorner p \urcorner)$. Here $e$ is the evaluation map $1 \times Y^{1} \rightarrow Y$ in Lawvere's notation. Since $1$ is a terminal object, it follows that $p$ is an isomorphism, and hence has both a left and right inverse. I hoped from here to conclude that $\ulcorner p \urcorner$ is also an isomorphism, but I end up going around in circles! Can anyone help?

Comment: Use the Yoneda lemma. What's $\text{Hom}(X, Y^1)$?

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think I'm supposed to know the Yoneda Lemma yet, and so I would like to prove this is the most elementary way.

Comment: BTW in the previous exercise we just proved that the points of $Y^{X}$ correspond to maps $X \rightarrow Y$. This seems related to your suggestion... I can conclude that $\hom (X, Y^{1})$ consists of points of $(Y^{1})^{X}$, i.e., of maps $1 \rightarrow (Y^{1})^{X} \simeq Y^{1 \times X} \simeq Y^{X}$. So to answer your question, $\hom (X, Y^{1})$ are points of $Y^{X}$.

Comment: Try to show, that the projection $ p: 1\times Y \to Y $ satisfies the same universal property as the evaluation map $ e: 1\times Y^1 \to Y $.

Comment: Many thanks @MarcOlschok. I got it!